# match specific characters in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string from which I want to check if it only contains characters that are allowed.

Allowed are only the letters a, b, c, d, e, k. I thought of something like this:

```
var string1 = "abcdekabc"
if (string1 contains only a,b,c,d,e,k) {
  document.write("everything is fine");
} else { 
  document.write("there is one or more character that is not allowed");
}
```

How can I do this? Is there a regex that would help me? Unfortunately I don't have experience with regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is a regexp :

```
var pattern = new RegExp('[^abcdek]', 'i');
var string1 = "abcdekabc";
if(!pattern.test(string1)){
    document.write("everything is fine");
} else { 
    document.write("there is one or more character that is not allowed");
}
```

Which can be reduce to :

```
var string1 = "abcdekabc";
if(!(/[^abcdek]/i).test(string1)){
    document.write("everything is fine");
} else { 
    document.write("there is one or more character that is not allowed");
}
```

If you prefer, you can go the other way arround (not checking illegal characters) :

```
var string1 = "abcdekabc";
if((/^[abcdek]+$/i).test(string1)){
    document.write("everything is fine");
} else { 
    document.write("there is one or more character that is not allowed");
}
```